# When puppet exec's as a user, how can I get environment set for that user?

Tags: puppet

I've noticed that when I use the `user` option on `exec`, it doesn't take the environment of the specified user.

```
$ sudo -i puppet apply -e "exec { '/usr/bin/env': logoutput => true, user => nobody}" 
notice: /Stage[main]//Exec[/usr/bin/env]/returns: SHELL=/bin/bash
notice: /Stage[main]//Exec[/usr/bin/env]/returns: USER=root
notice: /Stage[main]//Exec[/usr/bin/env]/returns: USERNAME=root
notice: /Stage[main]//Exec[/usr/bin/env]/returns: PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games
notice: /Stage[main]//Exec[/usr/bin/env]/returns: MAIL=/var/mail/root
notice: /Stage[main]//Exec[/usr/bin/env]/returns: PWD=/root
notice: /Stage[main]//Exec[/usr/bin/env]/returns: HOME=/root
notice: /Stage[main]//Exec[/usr/bin/env]/returns: LOGNAME=root
notice: /Stage[main]//Exec[/usr/bin/env]/returns: executed successfully
```

So while the command runs as `nobody`, `USER`, `HOME`, etc. aren't set as expected. Is there any way I can get `exec` to simulate a login shell so that the environment is setup as expected?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's no way to get `exec` to simulate a login shell. You can always use `su -` (as [suggested](https://serverfault.com/a/385321/9060) by [womble](https://serverfault.com/users/1375/womble)) to get produce a login shell, but if all you want are environment variables *controlled* by Puppet, just use the parameter `environment`.

Answer (score 7):

Sure, run the command via `su -` rather than specifying the user in the manifest.